# Regulate Up down key navigation action in select list

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm referring [this link](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache) for auto-complete search with caching. After reaching down bottom of suggestion drop down with down arrow, do not start from top. Similarly top does not go to bottom.

How do I achieve this. Can anybody suggest me?

Comment: From what I see, the selection wraps around perfectly. Even scrolls through what you just typed, in a similar way to the browser's address bar. What is your target behaviour again?

Comment: Thanks.. I got my query resolved here
http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/tu5sbraw/